# jQuery DataTables Not Sorting Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable

I have a jQuery datatable with 7 columns. The 6th column contains string data and is sortable but it won't sort properly. The rest of the colums sort just fine.

Has anyone experienced an issue with jQuery datatables like this? I cannot find a solution. =(

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI" : true,
   "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
   "aLengthMenu" : [ [ 5, 15, 25, 50 ], [ 5, 15, 25, 50 ] ],
   "iDisplayLength" : 15,
      "oLanguage" : {
  "sEmptyTable" : "empty"
   },
     "aoColumnDefs" : [ 
         { "bSortable" : false, "aTargets" : [ 0 ] },
      ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<table id="example">
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>Carl [org][c]org/org</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
<tr><td>DER</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "**but it won't sort properly**" - How so?

Comment: You want to sort alphabetically, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it works properly here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

</head>
<body>
      <table id="example">
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Carl [org][c]org/org</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DER</td></tr>
  </table>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu" : [ [ 5, 15, 25, 50 ], [ 5, 15, 25, 50 ] ],
        "iDisplayLength" : 15,
        "oLanguage" : {
                          "sEmptyTable" : "empty"
                          },
        "aoColumnDefs" : [
           { "bSortable" : false, "aTargets" : [ 0 ] },
        ]
      } );
    } );

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this, I got "Carl [org][c]org/org" on the first row and other rows are filled with "DER". If this is not the proper way, could you define "proper" here?

I am guessing you are missing the cdn or other stuff here. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can add a snippet here ?